# SharePoint 2013 search center result displays the html code from a multiple text line field

Tags: list-view, search-results, xslt-list-view-web-part, fast-search

I have a list library that contain two columns:

- **Title**: Single line of text field type
- **Body**: Multiple lines of text field type

I am experiencing a problem related to the way search results from the list are begin displayed: basically, when searching on any content inside the body field, the search result display the content of the field as HTML code, so I am getting something like

```
<div class="ExternalClass06285CF4FB8D45FE87B277D1A95B051E"> content goes here ....
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue on my search center result web application ?

Comment: Would you like to display it as plain text or as html?

Comment: I need to display the content as text and don't show the <div or the HTML code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have jQuery, you could do something like this in your display template:

```
jQuery(STSHtmlDecode(ctx.CurrentItem.yourprop)).text()
```

Comment: Can you give us more details about the above function and where I can add this script on the search result page ".../searchcenter/results.aspx" or on my master page ?

Comment: STSHtmlDecode is a utility function available from one of the search .js files from SharePoint. And you need to edit the display template for the item you are displaying. I have a sample doing something similar at http://techmikael.blogspot.no/2014/02/creating-custom-display-template-for.html